# Problem with numbers in csv file in Excel

Tags: excel, csv

I downloaded the csv version of the table present in this web-page https://d-place.org/parameters/DistToCoast_km#1/30/152. In the online version of the table the first column looks like this:

```
0.046161698
0.046405053
0.102112618
0.102112618
2,047.307804
2,029.644235
```

but when I open the csv file in Excel, these values look like this:

```
46161698
46405053
102112618
102112618
2047307804
2029644235
```

Can anyone tell me how to get a file usable in Excel in which first column values are the same of the first column online version and also look the same?

Comment: probably a local setting issue, I cannot reporduce.

Comment: are you using this button to download to csv: [download csv button image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMrTb.png) when I use it the file with the full table opens in excel with the right numbers

Comment: @dogwood, yes, I'm using that button!

Comment: What are your windows regional settings for decimal and thousands separator?

Answer (score 0):

you have to separate spaces with commas,

like `column1,column2,column3`

in your case i assume you have only 1 column like this

```
value1
value2
...
value n
```

in between the value you should not put any comma, otherwise it will be interpreted as a new column.

and your error was also that you didnt formatted excel sheets to display decimal numbers, so it cut out the zeros.

you have 2 ways:

1. you should format cells as text
2. format cells as decimal numbers

Comment: If you look at the actual csv there is no `,` in the number.  The website shows them but the output does not.

Comment: I've tried to do what you said, but nothing changed. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I opened the csv file directly clicking on it, without opening Excel before and clicking on Data > From text and importing the file. After opening the csv file clicking on it, Excel starts and the spreadsheet looks like this:

[image]

The I click on Data > Text to Columns > Delimiters: Comma, then I specify in the advanced settings that Decimal separator is ".", while Thousands separator is ",". After this passages, spreadsheet looks like this:

[image]